# Hide Dynamics 365 GUID at the end of the folders name in sharepoint online

Tags: crm, guid, sharepoint-online, dynamics-365

I am currently working on how to hide the GUID from the folder name in Sharepoint online. When I create a new account/customer in Dynamics 365 and the account is saved in Sharepoint online the folder will have a name like (Accountname_GUIDname), but I don't want the GUID to be displayed.

I know Dynamics 365 need it to find the place to store the documents. I have found ways to hide it but only up to crm 2015 not 365.

Is there a way to hide it from the folder name?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: @PaulHale You can try with this tool called "OrganizationSettingsEditor" and "OrgDbOrgSettings", I have not had time lately to test it. Maybe there has been a new version but I do not know. Hope you solve it, please let me know :)